# Trying to use nested Terraform modules from a private registry

Tags: gitlab, terraform, terraform-modules

I have an issue with Terraform and modules that call modules. Whenever I call my *nested* module the only output I get is:

```
No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.
Terraform has compared your real infrastructure against your configuration
and found no differences, so no changes are needed.
```

For context here is what I'm trying to do:

1. I have a simple module that creates an EC2 instance with certain options. (This module creates an aws_instance resource.)
2. I have a second module that calls my first and creates three of the above EC2 instances and sets a unique name for each node.
3. I have a Terraform project that simply calls the second module.

The two above modules are saved in my private GitLab registry. If I created a Terraform project that calls just the first module, it will create the EC2 instance. If I execute the second module as if it were just a normal project three EC2 instances are created. My issue is when I call the second module which then should call the first, but that it is where it falls apart.

I'm wondering if this configuration is actually supported. The use case I'm trying to test is standing up a Kubernetes (K8s) cluster. I create a module that defines up compute resource. I then create a second module that defines the compute modules with the options needed for a K8s cluster. Finally, I have a project that defines how many K8s nodes needed and in which region/availability zones.

I call this nested modules, but in all of my searching nested modules seems to only refer to modules and sub-modules that live inside of the Terraform project that is calling them.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. Here is how I create the resources and call the modules. These are simple examples I'm using for testing and not anything like the K8s modules I'll be creating. I'm just trying to figure out if I can get *nested* private registry modules working.

#### First Module (compute)

```
resource "aws_instance" "poc-instance" {
  ami        = var.ol8_ami
  key_name   = var.key_name
  monitoring = true
  vpc_security_group_ids = [
    data.aws_security_group.internal-ssh-only.id,
  ]
  root_block_device {
    delete_on_termination = true
    encrypted             = true
    volume_type           = var.ebs_volume_type
    volume_size           = var.ebs_volume_size
  }

  availability_zone = var.availability_zone
  subnet_id         = var.subnet_id
  instance_type     = var.instance_type
  tags              = var.tags
  metadata_options {
    http_tokens   = "required"
    http_endpoint = "disabled"
  }
}
```

#### Second Module (nested-cluster)

```
module "ec2_instance" {
  source = "gitlab.example.com/terraform/compute/aws"

  for_each = {
    0 = "01"
    1 = "02"
    2 = "03"
  }

  tags = {
    "Name"    = "poc-nested_ec2${each.value}"
    "service" = "terraform test"
  }
}
```

#### Terraform Project

```
module "sample_cluster" {
  source = "gitlab.example.com/terraform/nested-cluster/aws"
}
```

Comment: your source url seems to be wrong can you change it to this: ```git::https://gitlab.example.com/terraform/nested-cluster/aws```

Comment: It isn't a Git repo it's pulling the module from. It's a GitLab Terraform registry. This is the correct way to reference it, since I've successfully called modules in this way, just not modules that call other modules.

Comment: Can you verify that the module was downloaded properly?

Comment: It's hard to say what's going on here but it might be enlightening to look in the `.terraform/modules` directory under your working directory, which is where `terraform init` copies any modules obtained from remote sources, and make sure that the directories in there seem to contain the content you're expecting. Current versions of Terraform name the subdirectories after the module path, so from what you've said I'd expect to find a directory like `.terraform/modules/sample_cluster.ec2_instance` which has a file containing your `resource "aws_instance"` block.